# quick sort using filter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I am working on quick sort using recursion and filter, but the recursion is not working correctly.
It returns to the first half of the list sorted + extra (pivot and second half of the list from the last recursion), but second half of the list disappears.
Here is my code.

```js
const {
  List
} = require('immutable')
const quicksort = function(list) {
  if (list.size <= 1) {
    return list;
  }

  pivot = list.last();
  part1 = list.pop().filter((x) => x <= pivot);
  part2 = list.pop().filter((x) => x > pivot);

  return quicksort(part1).concat(list.last(), quicksort(part2));
};

console.log("quicksort: " + quicksort(List([4, 7, 3, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5])));
```

and it prints out

```
quicksort: List [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5 ]
```

The first time quicksort is called,

> part1 is [ 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1 ]
>
> pivot is 5
>
> part2 is [ 7, 6, 8, 7 ]

and basically, `[ 7, 6, 8, 7 ]` just disappears.

I appreciate any insight and advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`var`, `let` or `const` declaration is missing. Without those, `pivot`, `part1` and `part2` are *global variables*. After sorting `part1`, `part2` has been overwritten to an empty list (because that was the terminating circumstance of the previous branch of the recursion). Just `let` your vars be properly local :p. Like this:

```
let pivot = list.last();
let part1 = list.pop().filter((x) => x <= pivot);
let part2 = list.pop().filter((x) => x > pivot);
```

**Lesson**: `"use strict";`

Comment: I see. That explains it a lot. It works now!! Thank you so much!